# The unit circle has no cut points

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I am attempting to show that no point $(x,y)$ on the unit circle is a cut point.

What I have been trying to do.
Let $(x,y)\in S^1$ and let $X=S^1-${$(x,y)$}$=U\cup V$ where $U,V$ are nonempty  proper disjoint open subsets.  Then I choose an arbitrary point in each and attempt to get a contradiction.  For instance let $(a,b)\in X$ thus either $a\not=x$ or $b\not=y$.  WLOG assume $a<x$.

This is where I get stuck.  Do I need to set up cases?  Should I be using some neighborhood technique. Any help would be very much appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: Hint: Do you know that the real line is connected?

Comment: Yes but, I am actually planning to use this to show that the unit circle is not homeomorphic to the real line.

Comment: Hint to the hint: My hint is in connection to $S^1 - \{(x,y)\}$, not to $S^1$ itself.

Comment: So i should try to show that this set is homeopmorphic to the real line?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

From a to b there is arc ab and arc ba . x distinct from a and b is on only one of these arcs and thus is not a cut point.